Is there another way to select rows with null values within a function in python?
I've been working on cleaning a dataset and so far I've been using
missing_df = main_df[main_df.col.isnull()]

to select rows with null values under 'col'.
Since I'm using this a lot I'm trying to put it into a function but the same statement doesn't seem to work when 'col' is defined as a variable.
The function I tried defining:
def fcn(main_df_name, missing_df_name, col_name):
    missing_df_name = main_df_name[main_df_name.col_name.isnull()]
    return missing_df_name

fcn(main_df, 'missing_df', 'col')

I keep getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col_name'
I also tried adding pd.DataFrame but it didn't work.

Use main_df_name[col_name].isnull()
